# NSDateFormatter dateFromString wrong date for 12/31

Tags: ios, nsdateformatter

I'm getting the wrong date back for 12/31/2014.  Sample code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateF =[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateF setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
[dateF setDateFormat:@"MM/DD/yyyy"];

NSDate *date = [dateF dateFromString:@"12/31/2014"];
NSLog(@"Date for locale %@: %@",
      [[dateF locale] localeIdentifier], [dateF stringFromDate:date]);
date = [dateF dateFromString:@"01/01/2013"];
NSLog(@"Date for locale %@: %@",
      [[dateF locale] localeIdentifier], [dateF stringFromDate:date]);
```

The result returned is:

```
Date for locale en_US_POSIX: 12/335/2014
Date for locale en_US_POSIX: 01/01/2013
```

This brings up a number of questions.  1) how do I get the right date?  2) how can a month have 335 days?

Thanks to all,

Comment: Use `dd`, not `DD` for the day. Please look at the formatter spec.

Comment: Admittedly, the [date format pattern spec](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) is hard to find, but one needs to bookmark it, to be able to design formats.  Without it you're flying blind.

Answer (score 0):

"D" is day of year, you want "d" day of month.

You want:

```
[dateF setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
```

See: ICU [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) web page.

The other common mistake is using "Y" which is Week of Year instead of "y" year.